# Special Character (e.g. À,Ë) converts to questionMark (?) , validation issue against RegEx

Tags: java, json, angular, grails, groovy

I have gone through similar posts , but it didn't resolve my issue.

When I am providing special char from UI attribute(e.g First Name = Àvengers15) , which in turn is validating against Regex pattern

```
*******
    ([a-zA-Z0-9 +-.'/\\&-\\\u00a2\\\u00c0\\\u00c1\\\u00c2\\\u00c3\\\u00c4\\\u00c5\\\u00c6\\\u00c7\\\u00c8\\\u00c9\\\u00ca\\\u00cb\\\u00cc\\\u00cd\\\u00ce\\\u00cf\\\u00d0\\\u00d1\\\u00d2\\\u00d3\\\u00d4\\\u00d5\\\u00d6\\\u00d8\\\u00d9\\\u00da\\\u00db\\\u00dc\\\u00dd\\\u00de\\\u00df\\\u00e0\\\u00e1\\\u00e2\\\u00e3\\\u00e4\\\u00e5\\\u00e6\\\u00e7\\\u00e8\\\u00e9\\\u00ea\\\u00eb\\\u00ec\\\u00ed\\\u00ee\\\u00ef\\\u00f0\\\u00f1\\\u00f2\\\u00f3\\\u00f4\\\u00f5\\\u00f6\\\u00f8\\\u00f9\\\u00fa\\\u00fb\\\u00fc\\\u00fd\\\u00fe\\\u00ff\\\u0100\\\u0101\\\u0102\\\u0103\\\u0104\\\u0105\\\u0106\\\u0107\\\u0108\\\u0109\\\u010a\\\u010b\\\u010c\\\u010d\\\u010e\\\u010f\\\u0110\\\u0111\\\u0112\\\u0113\\\u0114\\\u0115\\\u0116\\\u0117\\\u0118\\\u0119\\\u011a\\\u011b\\\u011c\\\u011d\\\u011e\\\u011f\\\u0120\\\u0121\\\u0122\\\u0123\\\u0124\\\u0125\\\u0126\\\u0127\\\u0128\\\u0129\\\u012a\\\u012b\\\u012c\\\u012d\\\u012e\\\u012f\\\u0130\\\u0131\\\u0132\\\u0133\\\u0134\\\u0135\\\u0136\\\u0137\\\u0138\\\u0139\\\u013a\\\u013b\\\u013c\\\u013d\\\u013e\\\u013f\\\u0140\\\u0141\\\u0142\\\u0143\\\u0144\\\u0145\\\u0146\\\u0147\\\u0148\\\u014a\\\u014b\\\u014c\\\u014d\\\u014e\\\u014f\\\u0150\\\u0151\\\u0152\\\u0153\\\u0154\\\u0155\\\u0156\\\u0157\\\u0158\\\u0159\\\u015a\\\u015b\\\u015c\\\u015d\\\u015e\\\u015f\\\u0160\\\u0161\\\u0162\\\u0163\\\u0164\\\u0165\\\u0166\\\u0167\\\u0168\\\u0169\\\u016a\\\u016b\\\u016c\\\u016d\\\u016e\\\u016f\\\u0170\\\u0171\\\u0172\\\u0173\\\u0174\\\u0175\\\u0176\\\u0177\\\u0178\\\u0179\\\u017a\\\u017b\\\u017c\\\u017d\\\u017e\\\u0218\\\u0219\\\u021a\\\u021b]{1,60}) 
******
```

In my Groovy code,
In **response.JSON** I am getting - **first_name:?vengers15** which validates fine against the pattern using

```
*****
    pattern.matcher(val);
    boolean valid =  matcher.matches()
    valid = true
*****
```

I can guess it's because

```
*****
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
*****
```

being handled on UI Framework.

But when I am hitting the API with the same data as above directly through SOAPUI ,Provided the JSON payload with same data as though UI e.g. "first_name": "Àvengers15" . I am getting the same response.JSON as above ,**first_name:?vengers15** but the validations fails against the RegEx pattern

```
*****
    pattern.matcher(val);
    boolean valid =  matcher.matches()
    valid = false
*****
```

I tried handling UTF-8,thought this might be a problem in my Groovy Service class, but dosen't work.

```
*****
    byte[] ptext = attrValue.getBytes();
    String valueAfterUtf = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
*****
```

Also , tried setting
'Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' in Header , didn't work.

```
 1. Why am I getting question mark , if UTF-8 has been handled in case of UI.
 2. Why validation is failing through SOAPUI.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How you are checking what do you have in groovy code?

Comment: Try this: `"[0-9 +-.'/\\p{L}]{1,60}"`. The `\\p{L}` is used to match any kind of letter from any language.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what you’re doing, but I am certain that `attrValue.getBytes()` followed by `new String(ptext, "UTF-8")` is the **wrong** thing to do.  Strings all have the same charset no matter what.  Trying to alter it that way will only corrupt the data further.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to distinguish between "characters" and "glyphs": basically, a glyph is the graphical representation of a character, and the system will present you a replacement glyph in cases where the current font does not contain a glyph (a graphical representation) for the current character.

So at first you need to check whether the question mark that you see is the question mark or the current font's replacement glyph for unknown characters.

Next you need to check the code sets that you are working with: while Unicode and its encodings are able to present any defined character, there are other encodings that know only subsets. When you now translate a String from one code set into another, unknown characters will be replaced – often by a question mark – or you get an error of some kind.

So for verifying what the contents of your Strings really are, you should display the hex values of the characters, instead of just using `System.out.println()`.